# Legacy server app only supports SSLv3, possible to proxy and get TLS?

Tags: ssl, proxy

I have a Domino 5 server running on a Windows Virtual Machine on VMware, the host machine is a Mac. The Domino 5 server does not allow encryption algorithms any better than SSLv3.

Would it be possible to get the host to proxy the connection to the Windows program and therefore use TLS?

Answer (score 3):

There's a common configuration done with load balancers where a front-end web server terminates the TLS, and then relays the messages in plain-text to the application server, often called a "reverse proxy" setup:

[image: Diagram of SSL terminating at a load-balancer in front of the application servers]

You essentially want this setup with a server farm of one machine, which means you can do it all inside the VM :)

---

So the setup for you would be:

- Turn off SSL on the Domino server
- Firewall off the Domino port
- Set up a webserver on the same Windows VM as Domino -- Apache httpd or Nginx or IIS if it's Windows Server Edition *(Google for the appropriate guide)*
- Set up the front-end webserver in reverse proxy mode, redirecting all traffic to `localhost:domino_port` *(Google for the appropriate guide)*
- Set up the front-end webserver with modern TLS. You will probably need to get a new certificate since the SSLv3 certificate currently on the Domino server probably won't be accepted as a secure and modern cert for TLS1.2.

Comment: Connection to Domino server apps is strictly through browsers. We don't use clients in the system, other than through a backup scheme on the server machine. Does that change the above setup?

Comment: @Paul That makes it even more appropriate! I'll edit my answer.